# Omnichannel supervisor is only showing the agents when they are online

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel

I want an ability in omnichannel supervisor to see all the agents irrespective of their presence status. Currently I see only in omnichannel supervisor when the agents are online. Is this desired behaviour?

Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked about this ask with our product development team and got a confirmation that it is currently not possible with OmniChannel.

Please consider submitting this as an Idea on [Salesforce Ideas exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideasearch) so we can continue to improve the product.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 0):

You can display all agents, either online or offline, in Omni-Supervisor view by creating a Service Resource for each agent.
make Sure :-

1. resource type should be set to 'Agent',
2. Service Resource should be active.

Thanks! If helpful, please like
Ashwani Saklani